# Shell Script in cygwin inserting '

Tags: shell, cygwin

Hi so i made a simple shell script for junit testing using cygwin:

```
CLASSPATH=.:/cygdrive/c/classpath1:/cygdrive/c/classpath2
CLASSPATH=$(cygpath -pw "$CLASSPATH")
java -classpath $CLASSPATH org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.tiaa.plansponsor.web.controller.EndecaRunTest
```

However for some reason when i debug this, it comes out like this:

```
$ sh -x junit-script.sh
++ cygpath -pw '.:/cygdrive/c/classpath1:/cygdrive/c/classpath2'
+ CLASSPATH='.;C:\classpath1;C:\classpath2'
+ java -classpath '.;C:\classpath1;C:\classpath2' org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.tiaa.plansponsor.web.controller.EndecaRunTest
Error: Could not find or load main class org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
```

Now the problem is that for some reason it inserts --> **'** <-- apostrophe into CLASSPATH='. BUt WHY!? and how can i avoid this.

Thanks!

Comment: That is not the problem.  In bash, the apostrophe is a string delimiter.  It doesn't appear in the actual value of `$CLASSPATH`.

Comment: @MarkReed in the final output i see the apostrophes, after java -classpath. So i dont think it cuts it out in the end

Comment: Indeed. I saw that and then threw myself off. `set -x` wraps `'` around strings. It just does. Ignore them. The problem is, as @MarkReed says, not that.

Comment: That `+ java` line is not "final output" that's another `set -x` line. Stick an echo in front of that java command if you want to see what actually comes out (well sort of but probably enough for this).

Comment: If i run the command that prints out w/o the apostrophes in windows command it works fine, if i run it with apostrphes, it gives the same error that i get when i run the shell script.

Comment: So you might be right, echo "$CLASSPATH" does not print the apostrophe, but then i have no clue why this works in win command and not cygwin.

Comment: Try putting double-quotes around the `$CLASSPATH` on the `java` line in the shell script.

Comment: I tried, but same result.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that my classpath was this:

```
CLASSPATH=.:/cygdrive/c/classpath1:/cygdrive/c/classpath2
```

but it should have been this:

```
CLASSPATH=/cygdrive/c/classpath1:/cygdrive/c/classpath2:.
```

Comment: Which has nothing to do with apostrophes.

Comment: I wasn't bragging.  I would just suggest you rephrase the question to something more relevant for the benefit of future searchers.